# powershell script that pulls WMIC data from remote workstations

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a Powershell script that queries remote workstations for installed Windows updates looking for specific HotFixes (6 of them) and then reports back which ones (if any) are installed.

Query would get the remote host's name from a text file.

I found this script on Microsoft's site and tried to alter it, but I have no where near the skills needed to it.

```
Function Get-MSHotfix
{
    $outputs = Invoke-Expression "wmic qfe list"
    $outputs = $outputs[1..($outputs.length)]


    foreach ($output in $Outputs) {
        if ($output) {
            $output = $output -replace 'y U','y-U'
            $output = $output -replace 'NT A','NT-A'
            $output = $output -replace '\s+',' '
            $parts = $output -split ' '
            if ($parts[5] -like "*/*/*") {
                $Dateis = [datetime]::ParseExact($parts[5], '%M/%d/yyyy',[Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat)
            } elseif (($parts[5] -eq $null) -or ($parts[5] -eq ''))
            {
                $Dateis = [datetime]1700
            }

            else {
                $Dateis = get-date([DateTime][Convert]::ToInt64("$parts[5]", 16))-Format '%M/%d/yyyy'
            }
            New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
                KBArticle = [string]$parts[0]
                Computername = [string]$parts[1]
                Description = [string]$parts[2]
                FixComments = [string]$parts[6]
                HotFixID = [string]$parts[3]
                InstalledOn = Get-Date($Dateis)-format "dddd d MMMM yyyy"
                InstalledBy = [string]$parts[4]
                InstallDate = [string]$parts[7]
                Name = [string]$parts[8]
                ServicePackInEffect = [string]$parts[9]
                Status = [string]$parts[10]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the command line tool WMIC instead of the native Powershell WMI or CIM cmdlets? Get-WMIObject can connect using remote WMI, the CIM cmdlets use Powershell remoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I wrote up for a very similar situation:

```
ForEach($Server in $ServerList){
    $QFE=Get-WmiObject Win32_QuickFixEngineering -ComputerName $Server
    $IDRX = 3188732,3188743,3192392 -join '|'
    $QFE|?{$_.HotFixId -match $IDRX}
}
```

Mind you, I was looking for QFEs 3188732, 3188743, and 3192392, but you could easily modify that line for the ones you are looking for.

Comment: What syntax did you use for the output? Write-Host?

Comment: I did, yes, but you could use whatever you wanted.

Comment: I apologize, what I should have asked was... Could show me the syntax for the Write-Host portion?

Comment: Well, that kind of depends on what you're looking to get. What information do you want to see?

Comment: I would like to see which of the HotFixes, that I am looking for, are on the computer I am querying.

Comment: Did you try just running what I posted? That should list any hotfixes it finds, what computers it finds them on, and when they were installed.

Comment: I entered the script you gave me; I just added a single computer name to test it, then I ran it. It looked like it was doing something, but then it just ended up bring me back to the prompt without displaying anything.: `code` PS C:\windows>  $QFE=Get-WmiObject Win32_QuickFixEngineering -ComputerName PCQ22-back
    $IDRX = 3188732,3188743,3192392 -join '|'
    $QFE|?{$_.HotFixId -match $IDRX}

PS C:\windows>`code`

Comment: **Maybe that means that it didn't find any of those Hotfixes installed?

Comment: I suppose I should add that I was searching for these Hotifxes and not the ones in your sample: 4015549, 4012215, 4012212

Comment: That would imply that none of the hotfixes were found